# Converting csv files into shapefiles using python

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I have a csv file which i want to convert in a shapefile.
i have seen many questions being asked on this topic but the main problem is all the polygons were of the same size but in this csv file the polygons are of different size 
csv file is as follows:
Name,Area,geometry_of_the_TT
jjj,123,"POLYGON((73.953695297241 15.3555421329,73.951292037964 15.314816978733,73.986654281616 15.310015523128,73.982191085815 15.345775441645,73.953695297241 15.3555421329))"
lk,500,"POLYGON((73.938202857971 15.34362339739,73.944897651672 15.343375083164,73.943438529968 15.341554103151,73.942408561707 15.337084357624,73.941378593445 15.340395289421,73.937001228333 15.341471330955,73.938202857971 15.34362339739))"
"forest lake",800,"POLYGON((73.995494842529 15.291305352455,73.999614715576 15.287165708411,74.000301361084 15.283357163686,73.997898101807 15.281701253096,73.99377822876 15.282363618901,73.99377822876 15.284516293317,73.992576599121 15.287496882943,73.992919921875 15.289815090018,73.995494842529 15.291305352455))"

Comment: there should be no difference. once you have the correct format in your csv, and the correct syntax in your python it will simply continue reading the vertices until the end.

Comment: This is the code that i had written for reading the .csv file i mentioned above: